# Problems with a basic Python addition script.

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm basically trying to make a basic maths program for myself and started off with a two-digit addition program with random questions each time and I'm even managing to mess that up. Each time I input a correct answer it says it's incorrect everytime. Here's the code:

```
import random

digit_one = random.randint(0,100)
digit_two = random.randint(0,100)


print "What is %s + %s?" % (digit_one, digit_two)

answer = digit_one + digit_two    

userAnswer = raw_input()

if userAnswer == answer:
    print "Well done that's correct!"

else:
    print "That's incorrect!"
```

I'm working in 2.7 and the built-in IDLE IDE. I have a feeling I should have used a loop for this instead although I know I'll have to use one later on if I want it to keep reloading questions. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Hell no. Call `int` on the string. `input` is a horrible habit to get into.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I had to fight the urge to flag your comment as offensive... but seriously, no. Please don't go recommending things like python2s `input` or any other variation of `eval` to beginners without being extremely clear about all security and performance implications this has. And especially, don't do it in cases where there is a perfectly safe, fast, readable and obvious way to achieve the same task (which is `int` in this case).

Comment: @l4mpi "Offensive"? Whom did I offend? I am a strong advocate against the use of `eval` and even `literal_eval` as can be seen from my past answers. I personally never use `input` (the py2 one). BUT, it seems to me, that a lot of tutorials seem to use it, because most (or at least very many) beginners questions use it. So I suspected that `input` was quite common among beginners as your input gets parsed nicely and magically. And later one starts learning about types, type conversion, autoboxing, comparison, identity, etc... No intention to offend anyone.

Comment: @Hyperboreus The "offensive" part wasn't all that serious, thus the "but seriously" afterwards. And the target group for being "offended" would be everyone on SO dealing with entry level python questions and telling people to stop using `input`/`eval` over and over again ;) Anyways, you contradict yourself - if you're a strong advocate against `eval`, why recommend `input` which uses it? Especially to a beginner who should rather be steered away from bad habits like this. Feels like a C programmer who, faced with a question about how to repeat statements, recommends `goto` over `for`...

Comment: @l4mpi Thank you for the clarification. You are right. I have deleted the offending comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
userAnswer = raw_input()
```

`raw_input` returns a string. You need to explicitly convert that to `int` like this

```
userAnswer = int(raw_input())
```

since you are comparing it against `answer`, which is an `int`. You can confirm this by printing the types of those variables, like this

```
print type(answer), type(userAnswer)
```

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input()` returns a string (`str`). In your conditional you are comparing whether a `str` is equals to `answer` (`int`).

To fix this you could convert the input to an `int`:

```
userAnswer = int(raw_input())
```

Comment: Oh god that was so basic. This solution actually ran through my head briefly as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` returns a string. Turn it into an `int` to compare it with numbers:

```
>>> x = raw_input()
23
>>> x
'23'
>>> 23
23
>>> x == 23
False
>>> int(x)
23
>>> int(x) == 23
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a string with an integer. Try inputting 'userAnswer' as an integer, rather than a string, like so:

```
userAnswer = int(raw_input())
```